# letsencrypt certbot unable to renew certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to renew my certificate by doing doing this command:

```
/opt/letsencrypt/certbot-auto renew --no-self-upgrade
```

I am getting this error:

```
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mysite.test.com
http-01 challenge for mysite2.test.com
http-01 challenge for mysite3.test.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mysite.test.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. mysite2.test.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://mysite2.test.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5uevKfTmlKAyNSQZ207ZyWMtzvy51XKDb-mtAjd4Et4: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyr", mysite3.test.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://mysite3.test.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eeBiEE2z0YSI-SCh2_FAumtOXJS6SrL94UHGd8QgSSM: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyr". Skipping.

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.test.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
Running post-hook command: service haproxy reload
Output from service:
 * Reloading haproxy haproxy
   ...done.

1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mysite2.test.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://mysite2.test.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5uevKfTmlKAyNSQZ207ZyWMtzvy51XKDb-mtAjd4Et4:
   "<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
           <style>
               /* Copyr"

   Domain: mysite3.test.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://mysite3.test.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eeBiEE2z0YSI-SCh2_FAumtOXJS6SrL94UHGd8QgSSM:
   "<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
           <style>
               /* Copyr"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I've been banging my head for this for 2 days already and my website visitors are now complaining because they feel like my website is unsafe.

Any tips and help will be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Comment: is mysite3.test.com really your site?